# Toilet paper to the left or right?

Tags: bathroom, toilet

I just repainted my bathroom, and at the same time decided to replace the toilet paper dispenser.  I patched the holes from the previous TP holder, so I'm starting with a clean slate.

I'm at the point where I'm ready to install the new dispenser, but I'm not sure which side to hang it on.  the walls on both sides of the toilet are an equal distance away, so that is no help in making the decision.  And there are no obstructions or other factors to consider, so I'm having a difficult time trying to choose.

Is there a standard when it comes to this, or is it just personal preference?  Does handedness of the majority users play a factor?  Is there a standard height?

I know this seems like an odd question and it's possibly argumentative, but I have not been able to find any studies or research on the subject.  So I figured I'd ask for help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My suggestion would be to put it on the side that makes it invisible or less obvious when looking into the bathroom from outside it.

Answer (score 13):

Put it on the left side.  The other guy's suggestion is on point with most people being right handed, but righties are going to want to have a full reach to their left side with right hand.  The dispenser also being on the right side will probably actually present more of an uncomfortable reach.

Answer (score 5):

Have a seat and see what side/location feels better.  Being right handed, if it's any kind of stretch, I want it on the right side.  Otherwise, either side should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Most people are right handed so putting it at the right hand side is more handy.

Answer (score 1):

I normally put it on the left side (public toilet), due to the fact that the majority uses the right hand to do the wiping and cleaning. I feel much safer to pull the tissue using my left hand and to pass it to my right to do the action. I hope it make sense.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

As per the singapore standard is left hand side . only for your own house only you can provide any side but as per building accessibility in singapore is left hand side

Comment: Can you cite a reliable source, or is this simply an observation you've made?